# SSD not recognized after update from 16.04 to 18.04 LTS

Tags: upgrade, ssd

Samsung T7 SSD was working fine on 16.04 LTS. After upgrade to 18.04 LTS it is not appearing with lsusb, gparted, or fsdisk -l.  I also see that /var/log/dmesg does not exist.

I did the upgrade from the command line at the time of this posting. I am reluctant to upgrade to 20 LTS until I understand what went wrong with the 18 upgrade. Also, there is graphing software I use that is not supported on 20

I checked that the SSD works correctly on another system running 20.04 LTS, so it looks like something went wrong on the upgrade. Can anyone help?

Comment: please read [ask] then [edit] your question accordingly. In particular, how did you achieve the "upgrade from 16 LTS" and when. What error messages are you getting? Have you considered backing up important stuff and installing the latest LTS version (20.04.2) from scratch - perhaps trying it first with a bootable DVD/USB

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story.